# Store a list of values as a string when creating a table in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a table with 5 columns. COLUMN #2 (PROGRESS) is a comma seperated list (i.e 1,2,3,4 etc.) but when trying to create this table as either a string, variant or varchar, Snowflake refuses to allow this. Any advice on how I can create a column seperated list from a CSV? I tried to import the data as a TSV, XML, as well as a JSON file but no success.

```
create or replace TABLE AD_HOC.TEMP.NEW_DATA (
    VISITOR_ID VARCHAR(16777216),
    PROGRESS   VARCHAR(16777216),
    DATE DATETIME,
    ROLE VARCHAR(16777216),
    FIRST_VISIT DATETIME
)COMMENT='Interaction data'
;
```

**Goal:**

```
VISITOR_ID | PROGRESS  | DATE      | ROLE  | FIRST_VISIT 
111        | [1,2,3]   | 1/1/2022  | OWNER | 1/1/2021
123        | [1]       | 1/2/2022  | ADMIN | 2/2/2021
23321      | [1,2,3,4] | 2/22/2022 | USER  | 3/12/2021
```

Comment: You have a trailing comma `FIRST_VISIT DATETIME,`. Maybe that's all you needed to fix

Comment: Fixed! but still no success...

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are using to import the data into the table e.g. COPY INTO statement, file format, etc

Comment: @Blackdynomite Can you clarify what you mean by "no success"? Please include some more details on how exactly you're loading data to this table, what your source data actually looks like, and what errors you're getting, if any

Answer (score 0):

I encoded the column in python and loaded the data in Snowflake!

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = doc_data.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(doc_data.pop('PROGRESS')),
                          columns=mlb.classes_,
                          index=doc_data.index))
df
```